# Overflow evaluating the requirement for<'a> in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a following program that works fine:

```rust
use std::{ops, fmt};


#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct MyStruct<F>(F);


impl<F> ops::Neg for &MyStruct<F> where for<'a> &'a F: ops::Neg<Output = F> {
    type Output = MyStruct<F>;

    fn neg(self) -> MyStruct<F> {
        MyStruct(- &self.0)
    }
}


fn main() {
    let x = MyStruct::<i8>(3);
    println!("{:?}", - &x);
}
```

But if I move `println!` into a function it gives the error:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `for<'a> &'a MyStruct<_>: Neg`
```

This code:

```rust
use std::{ops, fmt};


#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct MyStruct<F>(F);


impl<F> ops::Neg for &MyStruct<F> where for<'a> &'a F: ops::Neg<Output = F> {
    type Output = MyStruct<F>;

    fn neg(self) -> MyStruct<F> {
        MyStruct(- &self.0)
    }
}


fn print_neg<T: fmt::Debug>(x: &T)
        where for<'a> &'a T: ops::Neg<Output = T> {
    println!("{:?}", - x); 
}


fn main() {
    let x = MyStruct::<i8>(3);
    print_neg(&x);
```

Why does it happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: I don't have enough info to provide a full answer beyond: Rust's type system is incorrectly determining which generic arguments to call `print_neg` with, which can be proven by providing the args: `print_neg::<MyStruct<i8>>(&x)`. Swapping your call for this one results in correct compilation

Comment: After some more investigation, it appears like this exact case is a known bug in the Rust compiler, as seen by [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39959#issuecomment-495353532), which has been open since 2017.

Since in your case it works to provide the type annotation, I would do that for now, despite how unwieldy it is, and then periodically check for Rust updates. I also tested on the nightly and beta versions to no avail :/